# adding method implementation inside interface in java 8

Tags: java, interface, java-8

While writing interface in java 8 i noticed behavior that i was able to define method in interface without any compile time error.

```
public interface AdvanceMediaPlayer {
    public static void playVlc(String fileName) {
        System.out.println("play VLC");
    }
    public abstract void playMp4(String fileName);
}
```

Please explain why is this happening. As far as I am aware we cant implement methods inside interfaces.

Comment: Java 8 introduces [Default Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html)

Comment: In Java 8 you can implement methods in interface (either static or default methods).

Comment: Maybe it’s a good idea to study the [“What’s new”](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-whats-new-2157071.html) documentation after installing a new JDK version…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java8 provides the ability to create default method implementations:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html

Answer (score 0):

> `Java 8` introduces `“Default Method”`new feature, which allows
>   developer to add new methods to the interfaces without breaking the
>   existing implementation of these interface. It provides flexibility to
>   allow interface define implementation which will use as default in the
>   situation where a concrete class fails to provide an implementation
>   for that method.

Refer [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) for more.

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 makes you able to declare static and default methods in interfaces.

A static interface method can not be overridden by the implementing class. It can only be called like this:

```
AdvanceMediaPlayer.playVlc(fileName);
```

A default method can be overridden by the implementing class. It is declared with the `default` keyword.